# Is the image of a simple winning set a equally simple set via the mapping that shows $\bf AD_{2} \Rightarrow \bf AD_{\omega} $?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299209/show-that-bf-ad-2-leftrightarrow-bf-ad-omega-nrightarrow-bf-ad-mathbb), Andres Caicedo's answer describe a mapping $\pi^{-1}$that shows why $\bf AD_{2} \Rightarrow \bf AD_{\omega} $ .

> We define a function $\pi$ by setting $\pi(x)=(n_0,n_1,\dots)\in\omega^\omega$. Say that the first $k$ moves of I are $1$s and the $k+1$-st is $0$. Then $n_0=k$. It is irrelevant what II has been moving so far. Say that, once I has played this first $0$, the next $j$ moves of II are $1$, and II's move after is $0$. Then $n_1=j$. It is irrelevant what I has been playing meanwhile. Say that, once II has played this $0$, the next $l$ moves of I are $1$s, and their $l+1$-st is $0$. Then $n_2=l$. Etc.

What can we say about this set-valued mapping $\pi^{-1}$? If $A$ is a Bore set, it seems to me $\pi^{-1}[A]$ should have a close ranking with $A$ in the Borel hierachy.

I tried the simplest case that $A$ is an uncountable closed set in $\omega^{\omega}$.Despite that $\pi^{-1}[A]$ is an uncountable union of closed sets that're neither open nor compact, I can't even tell whether it must be closed or not.

Comment: The abstract situation this illustrates is interesting. Greg Hjorth would talk about it sometimes. Of course, $\pi$ is Borel, so $\pi^{-1}[A]$ is Borel for any Borel $A$, but it may have higher complexity than $A$ does. Once $A$ is sufficiently high in the Borel hierarchy (past the complexity of $\pi$), we should have $A$ and $\pi^{-1}[A]$ essentially of the same complexity. But, in these situations in general, $\pi$ could be so complex that it hides any relevant information about Borel sets $A$ we may actually be interested in.

Comment: The particular $\pi$ described in the question is at quite a low level of the Borel hierarchy. It is continuous on its domain, which doesn't quite include all eleemnts of $2^\omega$. In Andres's answer to the earlier question, he extended $\pi$ to a total function, but at the cost of losing continuity. Nevertheless, $\pi^{-1}[A]$ will be at the same Borel rank as $A$ once that rank is above $2$.